# Problem with subsequent actions in PHP (alert message and header)

Tags: php, html, delay

I'm making a sign up action in PHP and need to place an alert message before redirecting the user to another page after this action is done, but whenever I place `header()` , it only redirects to the location without any messages
How to solve this?

```
if ($conn->query($query1)== TRUE)   {header("Location:signupend.php"); 
                    ;}
                    
                    else  die('Error with the connection' .$conn->error);
                    //Send alert message with the following text during validation
        }       else {echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Please repeat your password correctly")';
                    echo '</script>';};
        
    }       else {echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Your password must be 4 to 31 characters long")';
                    echo '</script>';};
    
   } else {echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Sorry, but this E-mail is already registered")';
                    echo '</script>';};
   
} else {echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Please fill all the fields")';
                    echo '</script>';};
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `header` function has to be run first (mean before page render html), so I don't think you can alert just before you set `header` to redirect to another page. But I think you can do this. Instead of using php for redirect, use Javascript

```
if ($conn->query($query1)== TRUE)   {
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert('....');'; // put your message here
    echo 'window.location.replace("'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/signupend.php");'; // redirect to page you want
    echo '</script>';
    die(); // die here so it will stop executing the function below
}
```

Hope it would help

Comment: Your code is useful and actually works, but now after redirecting it shows the last validation alert message and shows a blank page